# Conversion in SqlDbType.DateTime2 is approximative

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I'm working in C# and I need to add a value in a row of my SQL database. The value needs to be of type `DateTime2`. So I have to do things that way :

`query.Parameters.Add("Expiration", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = expiration;` because `expiration` is of type `DateTime`. When it's done, I can execute my query without any problem.

But the value inserted in the database is not strictly the same than the value `expiration`. `expiration` equals to `{09:48:47.6721345}` and the value in the database is `{09:48:47.6720000}`. So there's fractional seconds missing, because of the conversion.

How can I manage that problem ?

Comment: What is the fractional second precision set to in your DB?  The default is 7, but maybe it's set to 3 for that column?

Comment: @juharr yes it's 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem. In SQL datetime millisecond values are truncated.

Answer (score 0):

as you specified the field in the database is [`datetime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) and the value that you are sending is [`datetime2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) so the insertion query will send a `datetime2` value but the result will be saved as `datetime`

according to the docs `datetime` has .123 for precision where `datetime2` has .1234567

Comment: This isn't my understanding of what the OP said at all.  To me they are saying the DB column is `DateTime2`.

Comment: @juharr that's what I've understood, will wait for OP response

Comment: When they say _because expiration is of type `DateTime`_ I'm pretty sure they are talking about the variable they are sending to the DB, and not the column.

Comment: The DB column is `DateTime2`, you're right, and `expiration` is a parameter in my C# function

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that

> expiration is of type DateTime

If that's the case, your truncation happened when you create the expiration object, who then pass that truncated value to the database.

By the way, when you mention

> expiration equals to {09:48:47.6721345}

Did you see that value in a debugger, or is that the value you're trying to set expiration to (if the latter, the DateTime would've truncated to {09:48:47.6720000}, hence the value you see in the database).

Comment: I saw that value in a debugger actually

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Apparently the DateTime object do support precision up to 100ns. So it should've been able to handle it.

Comment: Yes, so maybe the conversion problem is somewhere else (maybe in the stored procedure), I'll check that out and I'll be back